# Cannot use ctrl+shift+U with RStudio

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, rstudio, unicode-entry

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in any text field inside the application the underlined u shows up but anything I type afterwards is taken as plain text.

I verified RStudio had already assigned that combination to another action but the problem persists after eliminating that shortcut.

Comment: If `<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<u>` is working in Gedit and/or Pluma, then you should contact RStudio support to address this issue.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, it works anywhere else. I will, thanks for the suggestion.